# Uncompress a zlib-compressed string in Java

Tags: java, python, zlib

I have a Java module that is receiving a compressed string from a remote Python script. The Python script compresses the string using `zlib.compress()`. I simply want to uncompress it in Java and display it to the user.

The [man page](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/zip/Deflater.html) for Java's built-in zip.Deflater object describes pretty explicitly how to uncompress something that has been compressed using `zlib.compress()`. However, this method does not work for me. Depending on which encoding I use, I either get "Incorrect Header Check" errors or the uncompression returns an empty string.

So, how am I supposed to uncompress this? The data are not getting corrupted in transmission, and the compressed string begins with "x\x9c", which is apparently appropriate for zlib-compressed stuff.

I've never dealt with compression/uncompression on this level before and am getting confused. For extra credit, I'd appreciate an explanation between compressed/uncompressed and inflated/deflated. According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2424945/are-zlib-compress-on-python-and-deflater-deflate-on-java-android-compatible) they are different, but most of the internet seems to use them interchangeably for zlib. This just makes trying to find a solution even more difficult, as I couldn't tell you whether I'm actually trying to "uncompress" or "inflate" these data.

Comment: You decompress using the Inflater class.

Comment: Thanks for the help, everyone. We decided to defer this functionality as it is a "nice to have" and was taking up too much of my time. Your comments were helpful, but nothing fixed the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The confusion has arisen because some bright spark started describing the zlib protocol as "deflate". It might help you to read the RFCs mentioned in [these Java docs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/zip/package-summary.html#package_description).

Also [this SO topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1089662/python-inflate-and-deflate-implementations) is quite relevant.

I suggest that you do

`print repr(zlib.compress("The quick brown dog etc etc")`

in Python (A) and compare the result from using the equivalent Java code using `Deflater` (B). Also ensure that you can Inflate B to recover your test input. Check that you are not suffering from unicode <-> bytes complications in Python or Java or both.

Have you tried doing a Python "deflate" as per the answer by @patthoyts in the SO topic that you quoted?

Comment: These were good ideas! These tests showed that the Python and Java I was using were equivalent compression algorithms and that the Java code could successfully uncompress some strings (just not the ones being sent from Python for some reason). We're deferring the functionality for now, but thanks for your help.

Comment: @UnicornZed: Please consider accepting the answer (big tick symbol to the left of the answer).

Answer (score 0):

It seems Python's `zlib.compress()` uses gzip, are you sure to create Inflater with nowrap parameter for gzip compatible uncompression?

Inflate/deflate is used only regarding DEFLATE algorithm I believe, whereas compress/uncompress is more general term.

Comment: I tried using the nowrap parameter to no avail. It was something I was unaware of, though, so thanks for bringing it to my attention.