# Does Python have a zip class that is compatible with Java's java.util.zip Inflater and Deflater classes?

Tags: java, python

I am working with byte arrays in Java 1.7. I am using java.util.zip's Inflater and Deflater classes to compress the data. I have to interface with data generated by Python code.

Does Python have the capability to compress data that can be uncompressed by Java's Inflater class, and the capability to decompress data that has been compressed by Java's Deflater class?

Comment: Additional reading, [are zlib on python and deflater on java compatible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2424945/are-zlib-compress-on-python-and-deflater-deflate-on-java-android-compatible).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you meant if there is something in python to handle ZIP format, there is. It is the module `zipfile`. Python comes with all batteries included.

Answer (score 2):

Commonly, these use GZIP. It would appear java.util.zip uses ZLIB and has support for GZIP.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/gzip.html
Is a python library that uses ZLIB and GZIP

Comment: That looks good, but it seems to deal with zip files. Is there a module for dealing with zipping internal objects?

Comment: If we're talking objects, that's a completely different animal than just compressing data. The best way to tackle something like that would be to convert it to XML (In Java, use JAXB. In Python, I'm not sure) and then compress the XML, if desired. The class structure should also be the same with getters/setters.

Comment: In Java, I am compressing a byte array, and sending it across a network via UDP. The message needs a byte array, which is what java.util.zip Deflater gives me.

Comment: Right... So you'd convert to an XML string, compress the string, then send that data. When you decompress on the Python side, you'd have the XML string back and could map that to an object. Keep in mind that you could lose data sending it over UDP though.